# How do i retrieve a value from an excel cell through python using the Cell method?, using python3.9 and openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, cell, return-value, openpyxl

Ive tryed to print a value using this code.

> print(sh1.cell(2,1).value)

being sh1, a valid worksheet of the workbook, and the cell (2,1) containing a string
btw i'm using pycharm

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
val = sh1.cell(row=2, column=1).value
print(val)
```

Another Way is:

```
val = sh1["A2"] #where A is 1st column and 2 is the 2nd row
print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out i was trying to retrive a value thas was added to the workbook after the last time i save the file, once i save it again, python retr